# Does redis support UDP between server and client

Tags: redis, udp

I want to send some log messages to the redis server. I want to use udp protocol to do this.

Does redis support UDP between server and client?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the [Redis protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol), RESP, is TCP based:

> ## Networking layer
>
> A client connects to a Redis server creating a TCP connection to the port 6379.
>   While RESP is technically non-TCP specific, in the context of Redis the protocol is only used with TCP connections (or equivalent stream oriented connections like Unix sockets).

What you could do is use a UDP proxy, but I'm not familiar with anything like that.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer especially in the streaming of things.... but you'll also need a Redis UDP client to pull it off

Comment: let's take it up with the powers that be... slight chance though

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, Why does one have to use a UDP proxy?

Comment: @Itamar Haber, Why do you suggest using UDP proxy? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking aloud here: you could use logstash as a proxy as ut supports UDP and TCP. It could listen for your UDP messages and forward them on TCP.

Comment: Here is another UDP to Redis proxy in NodeJS https://gist.github.com/nemtsov/a4a1c7c2627bd09114b1